# Sublime Text2 opens with a blank page and no menu bar on top and no side panel

Tags: sublimetext2

I feel kind of foolish asking this question but what do I need to do to get started in Sublime Text2. I just installed it and when I open the application I only get a blank page with nothing else, except the sublime text logo in the upper left corner. I can write code, I can open a document but there is no menu to do anything. I could use a little help here. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need should be under the view menu. So if you you to view > Side Bar > Show Side Bar it will show the directory structure of the current project. There is also show tabs and show minimap.

I would suggest exploring the menus and Googling it.

Comment: I don't see a menu at all. There's nothing but a blank page, except for the sublime text logo in the upper left corner. I can write code, I can control + o to open a document, I can control + n to start a new document. My problem is that I don't have a menu bar at all to select anything.

Comment: Something strange just happened. I was experimenting with key combinations and typed alt + v and a menu bar at the top appeared with all the commands. But when I released the keys the menu bar disappeared. So I can do key board commands even if I don't have a menu to interact with. My next step is to find out a way to keep the menu bar. I even saw the show  console command.

Comment: Okay everything's fine now. I clicked on show menu and the menu stayed. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

`Command-K, Command-B` opens the sidebar.

Check out the `View` dropdown menu. Shortcuts are usually shown out to the side.

And also checkout out [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) for plugins.